# Average by distinct rows sql

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
Name          cost        profit
Iphone         400         50
Xperia          300         40
Galaxy         420         55
Xperia          330         50
Iphone         600         70
```

I would like to have a table like this:

```
Name      avg(cost)   avg(profit)
Iphone       500              60
Galaxy       420              55
Xperia        315              45
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please make a short complete example of the code you've tried and explain what results it gives and what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot:

`SELECT Name, AVG(cost), AVG(profit) FROM 'table_name_here'
 GROUP BY Name`